# Google Drive apis > revisions > publishedLink <undefined> for a document

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Google Drive apis > revisions provides documentation for publishing Google Docs. when we access revision resources, we can get revision ids, exportLinks etc as mentioned in documentation.

There is one property 'publishedLink' mentioned in documentation which we can update and access. I tried it. In the request response, I get publishedLink for a spreadsheet, but I get **publishedLink:** ***undefined*** for a google docs document. What should be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

For Google docs it doesn't seem to populate the publishedlink string but you can easily build it yourself. As I use PHP heres what I use:

```
print "https://docs.google.com/document/d/".$fileId."/pub";
```

$fileId is the id of the published file.

An example link would look like this
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1oKGvOIPjjGLRN1kYYVvNTgV_VDKt8NKcLFJuGiO-sDI/pub